# Internal error while adding a new checkIn policy for VS2008 in Windows 7

Tags: checkin-policy

I have created a CheckIn policy using Visual C# 2008 and i am trying to add it to VS2008 checkIn policies in Windows 7. I have created a key(CheckForCommentsPolicy) in  `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\TeamFoundation\SourceControl\Checkin Policies` and added value \CheckForCommentsPolicy.dll. After i opened VS2008 and i cant find newly added policy in the source control!.Later I found out that i had referenced a new version of `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client.dll` file.So i added reference to same version of .dll.Now checkIn policy is visible in list but while adding some internal error occuring. 
[image]

Same code built in VS2012 is working fine in VS2012.
Why its not working in VS2008?anything i am missing?

Comment: You need to add a value of the AssemblyName **without** the `.dll`

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21480219/736079