# VS 2013 doesn't see my custom check-in policies

Tags: visual-studio-2013, vsix, checkin-policy

I have custom check-in policies deploying via VSIX. Now I'm trying to use them in Visual Studio 2013.

**What I did:**
I opened my policies in VS 2013. Changed "Install Targets" in vsixmanifest to [10.0, 13.0).
Then built project, installed VSIX and opened both VS.

VSIX project uses .NET Framework 4.5, policies project uses 4.0.

**What I have:**

- Last version of my policies in `C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0Exp\Extensions` directory
- Copies of policies for both 2012 and 2013 VS in `C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0(and 12.0)\Extensions`
- Key with path to policies in registry for both VS in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0_Config(and 12.0_Config)\TeamFoundation\SourceControl\Checkin Policies`

Now, when I want to apply them in `Team Project Settings -> Source Control -> Check-in Policy -> Add`, I can choose my custom policies in VS 2012, but VS 2013 just doesn't see them.

What can I do to fix it?

**UPD:**

So, I solved my problem by changing assembly version of `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client` from 11.0 to 12.0
**AND**
.NET Framework version in policies project from 4.0 to 4.5

Comment: Checkin policies reference some assemblies that are Visual Studio version specific, you'll need to change the references to the VS2013 ones and recompile.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson thanks, that helped! but now VS2012 doesn't see policies. is there a better way to make policies for both VS's than putting two ddl's with different versions to VSIX?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, sorry.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As the Original Poster has posted, the version of .NET and of the referenced Client Object Model:

- For Visual Studio *2005*, you need to reference the `8.0.0.0` assemblies and your project must be an AnyCPU .NET 2.0 project.
- For Visual Studio *2008*, you need to reference the `9.0.0.0` assemblies and your project must be an AnyCPU .NET 3.0 project.
- For Visual Studio *2010*, you need to reference the `10.0.0.0` assemblies and your project must be an AnyCPU .NET 4.0 project.
- For Visual Studio *2012*, you need to reference the `11.0.0.0` assemblies and your project must be an AnyCPU .NET 4.0 project.
- For Visual Studio *2013*, you need to reference the `12.0.0.0` assemblies and your project must be an AnyCPU .NET 4.5 project.
- For Visual Studio *2015*, you need to reference the `14.0.0.0` assemblies and your project must be an AnyCPU .NET 4.6 project.

If you have multiple versions of Visual Studio installed, you need to deploy the assembly multiple times, once for each version of Visual Studio. These assemblies must have the same `AssemblyName` and the same `AssemblyVersion` and be signed with the same strong name.

The policies must each be registered in the registry under the following keys:

- `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\{VisualStudioVersion}\TeamFoundation\SourceControl\Checkin Policies`
- `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\{VisualStudioVersion}\TeamFoundation\SourceControl\Checkin Policies` (64 bit OS only)
- `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\{VisualStudioVersion}_Config\TeamFoundation\SourceControl\Checkin Policies` (should be added automatically by running `devenv /setup`)

A [more extensive walkthrough can be found on my blog](http://blog.jessehouwing.nl/2014/01/creating-custom-check-in-policy-pack.html).

Comment: I'm using VSIX to distribute my checkin policies to VS 2012 and VS 2013? I have it working using two separate VSIX projects; one that targets 2012 and one that targets 2013? Since the 2012 and 2013 checkin policy assemblies need to have the same AssemblyName, is there a way I can deploy to both versions of VS using a single VSIX package project? Thanks.

Comment: So far I'm using different vsix's as well, I suggest posting a new question for this.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, a custom policy working on VS 2008/2010 don't install correctly in vs2013. Finally I opened the custom policy project in VS 2013, then I readded Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client reference and compile it. Now it works and recognize as the same policy that VS2010.